# Text to columns pandas

Tags: python, split, multiple-columns

I'm trying to figure out how to take column Name, and split it into 6 columns of data.  The headers would be Name, ND1, Time1, Time2, ND2, Time3. I basically want to do text to columns like you would do in excel. I really have no idea how to make this happen.

[image]

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')

df2 = df1['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True))
```

Comment: try to `split` by `spaces` , not by `commas`

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and add text.

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using split method.

```
df[["Name1", "ND1", "Time1", "Time2", "ND2","Time3"]] = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True)
```

By default, separator in split is whitespace, but you can enter manually. It will create six columns with given name and will keep current "Name" Column also. Keep in mind that you cannot create new columns with same name, that's why keep the column name is "Name1".
Later, you can delete current "Name" column using drop method if you need to.

```
df.drop("Name",axis=1)
```